# More than one Poincare-invariant vacuum in case of spontaneous symmetry breaking?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, symmetry-breaking, poincare-symmetry

It is said in axiomatic quantum field theory approach that Poincare-invariant vacuum is unique. However, in case of spontaneous symmetry breaking - such as Mexican hat example - it seems that more than one Poincare-invariant vacuum exists, even considering for quantum corrections.

Is this correct understanding?